# How to deploy a flutter app using VS code and windows

Tags: flutter

I am trying to deploy my app done using Flutter and the text editator VS, but I can't get the keytool for it.

Someone can give me a hint please?

Thank you.

Comment: deploy where ? and the question has many grammatical and spelling mistakes. Always double check your question before posting

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) link for the official release documentation.

On Windows use this command to generate the signing keystore file -

```bsh
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:/Users/USER_NAME/key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key
```

If you don't have `keytool` then make sure latest Java Development Kit is installed and its configured in your `PATH` environment variable.